# React component wont re-render ChartJS chart with redux props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, chart.js

I'm having a problem triggering React to re-render the chart made with ChartJS, I dunno whether I need to destroy the current chart and create a new one every time but I swear it was working before and now it isn't and I can't figure out why T-T

Here's my code for the component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from 'chart.js';


class ChartComp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data:[]
    }

    this.drawChart = this.drawChart.bind(this)
  }


  drawChart(){

    var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: this.props.chartData,
            datasets: [{
                data: this.props.chartData,
                label: "Active Users",
                backgroundColor: 'white'
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            mode: null,
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'User Activity',
              color: 'white'
            }
          }
        });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawChart();
  }


  componentDidMount() {


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{flex:1}}>
        <canvas style={{height:'px !important'}} id="line-chart" width="100%" ></canvas>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    'mapData' : state.mapData,
    'chartData': state.chartData
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {

  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(ChartComp)
```

I inspected the props and everything is fine, it receives a longer Array every time it gets updated but for some reason it doesn't trigger a re-render of the component.

I hope one of you has more experience with this than me that can point me in the right direction,

here is the reducer:

```
let initalState ={
  mapData: [],
  chartData: []
}

const rootReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE-CHART":
      return Object.assign({}, state, { chartData: action.payload });
      break;
    case "UPDATE-MAP":
      return Object.assign({}, state, { mapData: action.payload });
      break;
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate is not being called when the props update, why is that?

Comment: So, you see that componentDidUpdate() is called but not render()? Can you show the reducer and actions?

Comment: @samsonthehero added the reducer code at the end

Comment: can you confirm by console logging in the render, that is the render being called?

Comment: It looks like you may be mutating `this.props.chartData` somewhere in the action creator or reducer, and react is not updating as a result because `this.props.chartData` is still pointing to the same list (all be it longer now). 
I'd recommend trying `Object.assign({}, state, { chartData: action.payload.slice() });` in your reducer to make a copy of the list.

Comment: also, your render doesn't use any dynamic values. how can  you tell that the render is not being called?

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin that did it!

Comment: Also, with chartJS, I'd recommend creating one instance of the chart and rendering that, rather than creating a new one with every call to `drawChart()`. Then when your component updates, you can pass the new values to the chart and it will rerender itself. It's expensive to create a new chart on every render.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned this in a comment, but will add officially as the answer since it resolved the problem.

It looks like you may be mutating `this.props.chartData` somewhere in the action creator or reducer, and react is not updating as a result because `this.props.chartData` is still pointing to the same list (all be it longer now). I'd recommend trying `Object.assign({}, state, { chartData: action.payload.slice() });` in your reducer to make a copy of the list.